# Dynamic import in useEffect causes constructor to be called twice

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-ref, dynamic-import

I'm dynamically importing `@vimeo/player` in `useEffect` but when setting up `Player` I'm getting `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: You must pass either a valid element or a valid id.` which comes from this part in the Vimeo script:

```
if (!isDomElement(element)) {
  throw new TypeError('You must pass either a valid element or a valid id.');
}     } // Already initialized an embed in this div, so grab the iframe
```

So I guess the `new Player` constructor is called twice for some reason?
This error does not appear when I use a normal import - even though it seems `setup` is called twice no matter if dynamic import or not so I'm a bit confused why this error only appears with the dynamic import.
I tried adding a cleanup function but that also doesn't help - grateful for any pointers!

```
useEffect(() => {
    let isSetup = false;
    async function setup() {
        if (!isSetup) {
            const { default: Player } =  await import('@vimeo/player');
            playerRef.current = new Player(
                playerRef.current,
                playerConfig,
            );
            isSetup = true;
            playerRef.current.on('loaded', () => setIsLoading(false));
        }
    }


    if (playerRef.current) {
        setup();
    }

    return () => {
        isSetup = false;
        playerRef.current.destroy();
    };
}, [playerRef]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think any import is causing the issue.

I suggest removing the `useEffect` hook, because it should only be executed when the `playerRef` changes right? So you can port your code into a `useCallback`.

```
import { useCallback} from 'react';

// Open component
// ...
  const onPlayerRefChange = useCallback((node) => {
    // Insert your code here and `node` will be the mounted html element
 )};
// ...
// Close component
```

In your jsx use the ref attribute like this:

```
 <div ref={onPlayerRefChange}></div>
```

This wat the `onPlayerRefChange` function will only be called when the ref changes (should be 1 time if not the element changes multiple times and there is another bug in your code).

I'm not sure what the use for `isSetup` is, but if you want to use that I suggest moving it in a `useState`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `ref`s the `useEffect`'s dependencies. React doesn't track `ref`s state.

Your code is probably run two times because of the `StrictMode`.